# Expression type must be BOOLEAN dont know why

Tags: delphi

[Here is where the error is in my Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL1oP.png)

This is the Code:

```pascal
{=================================================================================}

procedure TFormGameSettings.pnlPlayerColor1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PlayerColorDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FSpieler1farbe := PlayerColorDialog1.Color;
    PanelColorChange;
  end;
end;

{=================================================================================}
procedure TFormGameSettings.pnlPlayerColor2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if PlayerColorDialog2.Execute then
  begin
    FSpieler1farbe := PlayerColorDialog2.Color;
    PanelColorChange;
  end;
end;
{=================================================================================}
```

i dont really know how to fix the problem im pretty new to delphi.
Before i changed the color in the "PlayerColorDialog2.Color;" everything was fine know i get BOOLEAN.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you mean the red underlined lines, they may be a result of a buggy scanner. Just try to compile the code and see if any error crops up. If so, mark your code (not an image) with where the error is reported, as well as the error text. Don't use images to document stuff...

Comment: You have a bug in ``pnlPlayerColor2Click``: ``FSpieler1farbe`` has to presumably to be ``FSpieler2farbe``

Comment: If ErrorInsight keeps on marking errors in code where clearly are none, try to close the project and reopen it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"If ErrorInsight keeps on marking errors in code where clearly are none, try to close the project and reopen it!"*** @Delphi Coder

Your comment helped, I guess it was a bug.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks like a comment rather then an answer